# Printed a list, three dots appeared inside sublists

Tags: python, list

I printed out the contents of a list, and i got the following output:

```
[[...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...]]
```

What are these strange dots?

I used python 2.7.3

Comment: What list did you print?  You need to show your actual code.

Comment: How did you make the list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably you accidentally built a list containing a reference to itself (or here, lots of references):

```
>>> a = ['x']
>>> a
['x']
>>> a[0] = a
>>> a
[[...]]
```

The three dots are used so that the string representation doesn't drown in recursion.  You can verify this by using `id` and the `is` operator:

```
>>> id(a)
165875500
>>> id(a[0])
165875500
>>> a is a[0]
True
```

Comment: This was also implemented in `2.7`... Never seen before today.