# Why does Python list of lists behave differently depending on their declaration?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a list inside another list in Python. I noticed that depending on the declaration the final (outer) list behaves differently.

I tried to create list of lists in two different ways. Both cases gave me varies results.

```py
#Case 1
def test():
    lt1 = lt2 = list()
    for i in range(0, 10):
        for j in range(0, 2):
            lt1.append(j);
        lt2.append(lt1);
        lt1 = [];
    print (lt2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

```py
#Case 2
def test():
    lt1 = list()
    lt2 = list()
    for i in range(0, 10):
        for j in range(0, 2):
            lt1.append(j);
        lt2.append(lt1);
        lt1 = [];
    print (lt2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

In case 1 the output is
[0, 1, [...], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]

In case 2 the output is
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
which is the expected answer for my implementation.

I wanted to know why the first code snippet acts differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference vs Assignment in Python mutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092937/reference-vs-assignment-in-python-mutable-objects)

Comment: In Case1, `lt1 = lt2 = list()`, `lt1` and `lt2` point to the same list, so modifying one modifies the other, which doesn't hold true in Case 2

Comment: The two line equivalent of `lt1 = lt2 = list()` is actually `lt1 = list()`, `lt2 = lt1`. i.e. `lt2` is just a reference to the same list `lt1` refers to. I think the take away here should be don't use multiple assignments in 1 line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the first line:

```
>>> a = b = []
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[]
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a is b
False
>>>
```

With one line as in case 1, it contains the same object, so:

```
>>> a = b = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
>>> b
[1]
>>>
```

Which doesn't happen with two lines:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
>>> b
[]
>>>
```

So simply because the first line of case 1 has `a` and `b` that are the exact same objects, unlike the second case's fist line, that are same values, but different `id` (`id(a) == id(b)` is the same as `a is b`).

Comment: @deb17dj See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851581/python-printed-a-list-three-dots-appeared-inside-sublists

Comment: Thanks. That answers part of my question. My  doubt now is what is the [...] and what causes it?  
>>> a = b = list()  
>>> a  
[]  
>>> b  
[]  
>>> a is b  
True  
>>> b.append(0)  
>>> b.append(1)  
>>> a  
[0, 1]  
>>> b  
[0, 1]  
>>> a.append(b)  
>>> a  
[0, 1, [...]]  
>>> b  
[0, 1, [...]]

Comment: @deb17dj Read my link above, it's well explained.

Comment: @deb17dj Happy to help :-)