# How to get full ouput of a dictionary instead of "{'k1':val1,k2:{...}}"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Doubly_Linked_List:
    #O(1)
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        if value==None:
            self.head = {'value':None,'prev':None,'next':None}
            self.tail = None
            self.length = 0
        else:
            self.head = {'value':value,'prev':None,'next':None}
            self.tail = self.head
            self.length = 1
    #O(1)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'head:{self.head}\ntail:{self.tail}\nlength:{self.length}'
    def _navigate_to_pointer(self,index):
        pointer_before_insertion = self.head
        for i in range(index-1):
            pointer_before_insertion = pointer_before_insertion['next']
        return pointer_before_insertion
    #O(1)
    def _make_node(self,value):
        return {'value':value,'prev':None,'next':None}
    def append(self,value):
        if self.length==0:
            self.head = self._make_node(value)
            self.tail = self.head
            self.length+=1
            return None
        new_last_node = self._make_node(value)
        new_last_node['prev'] = self.tail
        self.tail['next'] = new_last_node
        self.tail = new_last_node
        self.length+=1

#test
a=Doubly_Linked_List()
for i in range(2):
    a.append(i)
print(a)
print(a.tail)
print(a.head)
```

I am trying to implement doubly linked list using dictionary data type in python 3.8. I am trying to test my code but I can't see the full output.

[image: screenshot of current output]

Comment: Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851581/python-printed-a-list-three-dots-appeared-inside-sublists) refers to lists, I wonder if your three dots mean that your dictionaries have a references to themselves which is then probably a bug in your construction of the linked list.

Comment: No it's not a bug of my implementation of Doubly Linked List. According to the answer of this question python was avoiding the output. And I tested the answer. My implementation is correct so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not a bug. I'm including some test code and output to clarify. What Python is doing is not print out any object that was already printed in order to avoid an infinite print out.

```
dlist = Doubly_Linked_List()
dlist.append(1)
dlist.append(2)
print(dlist)
```

Outputs the following.

```
head:{'value': 1, 'prev': None, 'next': {'value': 2, 'prev': {...}, 'next': None}}
tail:{'value': 2, 'prev': {'value': 1, 'prev': None, 'next': {...}}, 'next': None}
length:2
```

- Notice that when printing the `head` first the `...` is in place of the `prev` of the last item, because it was already printed.
- Notice that when printing from `tail` (going backwards) then the `next` of the eventually reached first item is replaced with `...` because it was already printed out (the item with value `2`).

The code, formatted, and also I gave you an `__iter__` method that would help you print out every item.

```
class Doubly_Linked_List:
    #O(1)
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        if value==None:
            self.head = {'value':None,'prev':None,'next':None}
            self.tail = None
            self.length = 0
        else:
            self.head = {'value':value,'prev':None,'next':None}
            self.tail = self.head
            self.length = 1
    #O(1)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'head:{self.head}\ntail:{self.tail}\nlength:{self.length}'
    def _navigate_to_pointer(self,index):
        pointer_before_insertion = self.head
        for i in range(index-1):
            pointer_before_insertion = pointer_before_insertion['next']
        return pointer_before_insertion
    #O(1)
    def _make_node(self,value):
        return {'value':value,'prev':None,'next':None}
    def append(self,value):
        if self.length==0:
            self.head = self._make_node(value)
            self.tail = self.head
            self.length+=1
            return None
        new_last_node = self._make_node(value)
        new_last_node['prev'] = self.tail
        self.tail['next'] = new_last_node
        self.tail = new_last_node
        self.length+=1
    def __iter__(self):
        pointer = self.head
        while pointer:
            yield pointer["value"]
            pointer = pointer["next"]

dlist = Doubly_Linked_List()
dlist.append(1)
dlist.append(2)
#dlist.append(3)
print(dlist)

for item in dlist:
    print(item)
```